# Jinja - Converting JSON to YAML

Tags: json, yaml, jinja2

I'm trying to convert my JSON input to a YAML format. I only need the key value pair of a few fields from the json but I'm not seeing the output i need. The fields i need as key value in my YAML is the `name` field as key and the `value` as the value.

JSON input:

```
{
   "Test":{
      "id":223,
      "name":"Test",
      "value":"None",
      "propertyId":223,
      "parentId":"None",
      "children":[
         {
            "Test 2":{
               "id":260,
               "name":"Test 2",
               "value":"Connected",
               "propertyId":260,
               "parentId":223,
               "children":[
                  {
                     
                  }
               ]
            },
            "This is a test":{
               "id":1058,
               "name":"This is a test",
               "value":"",
               "propertyId":1058,
               "secured":0,
               "parentId":223,
               "children":[
                  {
                     
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Info":{
               "id":1270,
               "name":"Info",
               "value":"",
               "propertyId":1270,
               "secured":0,
               "parentId":223,
               "children":[
                  {
                     "More info":{
                        "id":1271,
                        "name":"More info",
                        "value":"N/A",
                        "propertyId":1271,
                        "secured":0,
                        "parentId":1270,
                        "children":[
                           {
                              
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     "Another info":{
                        "id":1272,
                        "name":"Another info",
                        "value":"",
                        "propertyId":1272,
                        "secured":0,
                        "parentId":1270,
                        "children":[
                           {
                              "We Got more":{
                                 "id":1273,
                                 "name":"We Got more",
                                 "value":"",
                                 "propertyId":1273,
                                 "secured":0,
                                 "parentId":1272,
                                 "children":[
                                    {
                                       
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Jinja code:

```
{% macro transform(item) %}
  {% set result = {} %}
  {% for key, value in item.items() %}
    {% if value is mapping %}
      {% set result = result | combine(transform(value)) %}
    {% else %}
      {% set result = result | combine({item['name']: item['value']}) %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {{ result }}
{% endmacro %}

{{ transform(['Test']) | to_yaml(indent=2) | safe }}
```

Current output from Jinja:

```
'  {}

  '
```

Comment: Depending on what version of YAML you want the output to adhere to, chances are that you wouldn't have to convert at all. Since [YAML 1.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.0/) (Jul 21, 2009) any JSON is bydefinition also valid YAML.